How to access the host's optical drive in a Gnome Boxes VM?
I'm not certain if Gnome Boxes supports disc drives (I'm willing to use the underlying virtualization software if needed). The drive is an internal UHD BD variant and predictably does not display on 'devices & share' → 'USB devices' when a VM is running. On both Linux and Windows guests Boxes presents a supposedly virtual 'QEMU DVD-ROM' drive to programs.
I have to use some Windows-only CD/DVD/BD ripping software (and may burn data on the latter format); Gnome Boxes thankfully has near-flawless support for Windows 10 at least (when the official image is provided).
